# add row number index in a variable based on the matching value of another file when the number of rows in both the files are different

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

File1 and File2 are two data frames with with two variables ID and Names. I want the following to do in R.

```
## File1 

   ID       Names
    1        Aman
    2        Raj
    3        Abhishek
    4        Gaurav
    5        Martin
    6        NA
    7        Anna
    8        Ravi
    9        Jai
    10       NA

## File2

   ID    Names
    1     Anna
    2     Jai
    3     Martin
    4     Abhishek
    5     Aman
    6     Ravi
    7     Raj
    8     Gaurav
```

Desired outcome: Index of File2 in the order of Names from File1 but retain all the entries present in File1 (even NAs).
For eg: "Aman" is in the first position in File1 and in 5th position in File2. So, in the output, I want 5 as the first number in the "layout" vector and so on.
I want to do this in R.

```
## Desired outcome:
    layout = 5 7 4 8 3 NA 1 6 2 NA
```

I tried this:

```
newtable <- merge(File1,File2, by = "Names", all.x = TRUE)
layout = arrange(newtable, id.x)[,3]
```

but did not work. Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `match` from `base R` to get the index

```
match(File1$Names, File2$Names)
#[1]  5  7  4  8  3 NA  1  6  2 NA
```

#### data

```
File1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, Names = c("Aman", "Raj", "Abhishek", 
"Gaurav", "Martin", NA, "Anna", "Ravi", "Jai", NA)), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

File2 <- structure(list(ID = 1:8, Names = c("Anna", "Jai", "Martin", "Abhishek", 
"Aman", "Ravi", "Raj", "Gaurav")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works perfectly:

```
newtable <- merge(File1,File2, by = "Names", all.x = TRUE)
layout = arrange(newtable, id.x)[,3]
```

I don't know how but now this method is also giving the same output. If for any of you this does not work, please mention in the comments.